# How do I say "Happy Valentine's Day!" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Assuming that such sentiments are expressed in Ukrainian, how do I say "Happy Valentine's Day!" in Ukrainian?

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happy_Valentine's_Day) doesn't have a translation for that phrase in any language, and I didn't come across the phrase in the Ukrainian Wikipedia article [День святого Валентина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

According to [Master Russian](http://masterrussian.com/russianculture/valentines_day.htm), the Russian (not Ukrainian) for it is "С Днём Свято́го Валенти́на!"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ukrainian it would be similar:

З днем Святого Валентина!

Answer (score 9):

You can also say "З Днем усіх закоханих!" ("Happy day of everyone in love!"), it is also quite widespread and sounds natural.

Answer (score 6):

This festival was just recently introduced to the Ukrainian culture, that's why you haven't find related phrases in the dictionary. People say, as you've seen in the previous answers, two basic phrases:

- З днем Святого Валентина! (*z dnem sviatoho valentynah*), meaning /I greet you (omitted)/ with the St.Valentines's day

or

- "З Днем усіх закоханих!" (*z dnem oosikh zakokhanykh*), meaning /I greet you (omitted)/ with the day of everyone in love